# Mongo Db aggregation pipeline with loop

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I have a collection which contains half million data, and i want an average for all months between the date i enter. Right now i am getting the data for whole year, but i want it seperated by single month i.e 12 data range for every single month.

Below is the aggregation pipeline i am using.

```
let filter = 'y';
const date = new Date();
let checkDate = moment().subtract(1.5, 'years')._d;
MeterData.aggregate([
      {
          $group: {
              _id: "$meter_id",
              // total: { $sum: 1 },
              totalEnergy: filter !== 'a' ? {
                $sum: {
                  $toDouble: {
                      $cond: {
                        if: {
                          $gte: [
                            "$date", checkDate
                          ]
                        },
                        then: "$energy.Energy",
                        else: 0
                      }
                }
                                  }
               } : { $sum: { $toDouble: 
                    "$energy.Energy"
                   } }
          },
               }
  ]);
```

Here i am getting totalEnergy for all year, in totalEnergy field, but now i want totalEnergy plus monthly calculations for the year i enter.
Any idea on how to do that. ?

Below is a sample document from the collection.

```
{"_id":{"$oid":"5e557779ed588826d84cef11"},
"meter_id":"1001",
"date":{"$date":{"$numberLong":"1509474600000"}},
"parameter_name":"hvac","voltage":{"unit":"V"},
"current":{"unit":"AMP"},
"powerFactor":{"unit":"phi"},
"angle":{"unit":"degree"},
"activePower":{"unit":"kwh"},
"reactivePower":{"unit":"kwh"},
"apparentPower":{"unit":"kwh"},
"frequency":{"unit":"hz"},
"thd":{"unit":"percentage"},
"energy":{"Energy":"5.7"},
"power":{"unit":"watt"},
```

As per suggested by Ryan Gunner, i got my answer which i am pasting below, i just have one more problem.

```
[
  {
    meter_id: '1001',
    month: '2017-10',
    totalEnergy: 0,
    averageEnergy: 0
  } + 11 more months......
]
```

Now what i need is the total of the energy for 12 months. For example total of totalEnergy field for all 12 months in a single variable.

Comment: Is it feasible for you to add 2 new fields: month, year ? ...calculated off your date field for your existing data - and added to your app's schema so they are entered for new records …. this would set things up to be both easier and faster to run....if you are going to be repeating this query frequently it would a worthwhile effort.....

Comment: I think you should better use method `toDate()` instead of `_d` property which might be for internal use of `moment` only.

Comment: @WernfriedDomscheit sure i will change that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

how about something like this?

```java
var startDate = new ISODate('2020-04-01');
var endDate = new ISODate('2019-04-01');

db.collection.aggregate(
    {
        $match: {
            $expr: {
                $and: [
                    { $gt: ['$date', endDate] },
                    { $lt: ['$date', startDate] }]
            }
        }
    },
    {
        $group: {
            _id: {
                meter: '$meter_id',
                month: { $dateToString: { format: '%Y-%m', date: '$date' } }

            },
            totalEnergy: { $sum: { $toDouble: '$energy.Energy' } },
            averageEnergy: { $avg: { $toDouble: '$energy.Energy' } }
        }
    },
    {
        $project: {
            meter_id: '$_id.meter',
            month: '$_id.month',
            totalEnergy: '$totalEnergy',
            averageEnergy: '$averageEnergy',
            _id: 0

        }

    },
    {
        $sort: { meter_id: 1 }
    }
    {
        $group: {
            _id: null,
            grandTotalEnergy: { $sum: '$totalEnergy' },
            monthlyData: { $push: '$$ROOT' }
        }
    },
    { $project: { _id: 0 } }
)
```

**update:** added grandTotalEnergy field and pushed monthlyData to an array.

Comment: Thanks ! It is working perfectly, but theres just one thing left which i am not getting as expected. I have edited the question for that, can you please check and reply back ?

Comment: Thank You .! Awesome Solution.